# How do I calculate the value in a cell and replace with new value in same cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

The cell value is currently 85.49. I need to add 50%, then add 6%, then add 10.00. THEN that new calculated value needs to replace the original value.

So the calculation I used is `=SUM(s2=(s2*.50))*1.06+10.00`. Now I need the $85.49 replaced with $128.23. I have several lines with this so I need to also be able to copy it down.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you need to do this one time? Create a column that does this and then copy > paste values over your original data. Do you need to do this automatically as values are entered? You have to use VBA.

Comment: Is the cell containing the $85.49 already using a formula to get that number? Where are you placing the formula you have given as an example in your question? Are you able to add a column? It would make things much easier. Otherwise, like Engineering Toast pointed out, it will require some VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add 50% of the starting value, then use that result to add another 6%, then add 10, then your formula is simply:

> A1*1.5*1.06+10

And the result if using 85.49 is **145.93**. So I may misunderstand your logic. But regardless, as pointed out, you cannot use an Excel formula to effectively replace the value in the same cell. This would create a circular reference. So as CharlieRB suggested, use a new column, or as CharlieRB and Engineer Toast both suggested, use a VBA sub to calculate and replace the value. Note you'll still need some action to initiate the replacement (clicking a button, or perhaps an event in the worksheet/workbook).

Comment: Very helpful to a point. And you guys are correct, it is 145.93, I typed the wrong number. When I add a column, do the calculation, then paste it over the original column, the value is gone. It populates #VALUE!.      What I am doing is I imported a sheet of items with prices at my wholesale cost, I need to change those values to have a 50% markup, and then add $10.00. (I found out I can leave out the 6%). but I can't figure out how to get the new amount to replace the original amount. and if I delete either column that value is gone.

Comment: When you paste it into the original cell, choose to Paste Values. You can do this using the Paste drow-down menu button (under Paste), or choose Paste Special then select Values, or select the Values option from the content-menu that is offered just after you Paste.

Comment: DeltaHotel - It worked! Thank you SO much!!!!! such a simple trick that I have used in other areas but never thought to do it this way. Thanks again!